# Sending email laravel form

Tags: email, controller, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to send emails with form details in. I succeed to send one with email information but when I'm trying to add more data, i get errors such as undefined var etc.

After sending the mail, I'd like to redirect to a new view saying ' Thx for contacting us" before getting back to index. Any help ? :(

**Controller**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use  App\Http\Requests\ContactFormRequest;

class AboutController extends Controller {
    public function create()
    {
        return view('contact');
    }
    public function store(ContactFormRequest $request)
{

   echo "<pre>"; print_r($request->all());
        die();


        function($message)
    {
        $message->from('wj@wjgilmore.com');
        $message->to('x@gmail.com', 'Admin')->subject('x');
    });

  return \Redirect::route('contact')->with('message', 'Thanks for contacting us!');
}}
```

**Form**

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'contact', 'class' => 'form')) !!}
        <h3>Prestation</h3>
        <label class="grid_16">
            <span class="label grid_5">x</span>
        {!!  Form::select('event_types', $event_types) !!}
        </label>

        <label class="grid_16">
            <span class="label grid_5">x</span>
            <input type="date" name="date"/>
        </label>

        <label class="grid_16">
            <span class="label grid_5">x</span>
            {!!  Form::select('personnes', $personnes) !!}

        </label>

        <label class"grid_16">
            <span class="label grid_5">x</span>
          {!!  Form::text('lieu') !!}
        </label>

        <label class="grid_16">
            <span class="label grid_5">x</span>
            {!!  Form::select('rayon_km', $rayon_km) !!}

        </label>

        <label class="grid_16">
            <span class="label grid_5">Tx</span>
            <ul class="grid_8">
            @foreach($accessoires as $value => $front)
                <li>
                  <label>
                  {!! Form::checkbox('accessoires[]', $value) !!}
                  {{ $front }}
                  </label>
                </li>
            @endforeach
            </ul>
        </label>

        <label class="grid_16">
            <span class="label grid_5">x</span>
            <textarea name="informations" rows="5" cols="70"></textarea>
        </label>

        <h3>Coordonnées</h3>
        <label class="grid_16">
            <span class="label grid_5"> x</span>
            {!!  Form::select('civilite', $civilite) !!}
        </label>

        <label class="grid_24">
            <span class="label grid_5"> x</span>
            {!!  Form::text('prenom') !!}
        </label>

        <label class="grid_24">
            <span class="label grid_5"> x</span>
            {!!  Form::text('nom') !!}
        </label>

        <label class="grid_24">
            <span class="label grid_5"> x</span>
            {!!  Form::text('telephone') !!}
        </label>

       <label class="grid_24">
            <span class="label grid_5"> x</span>
              {!!  Form::email('email') !!}
        </label>

       <label class="grid_24">
            <span class="label grid_5"> x</span>
            {!!  Form::text('telephone2') !!}
        </label>

       <label class="grid_24">
            <span class="label grid_5"> x</span>
            {!!  Form::text('horaires') !!}
        </label>

        <div class="grid_24">
        {!!    Form::submit('Envoyer', '', array('class'=>'btn btn-primary')) !!}
        </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**ContactFormRequest**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class ContactFormRequest extends Request
{
/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [

'prenom' => 'required',
'nom' => 'required',
'email' => 'required|email',
        //
    ];
}
}
```

**Email view**

```
<p>

Type d'évènement :  {{ $event_types }} </br>

Date de l'évènement : {{ $date }}

Nombre de personnes conviées :  {{ $personnes }} </br>

Lieu de l'évènement : {{ $lieu }}

Rayon Km :  {{ $rayon_km }} </br>

Accessoires nécessaires :  {{$accessoires}} </br>

Civilité : {{ $civilite }}

Nom : {{ $nom }}

Prénom : {{ $prenom }}

Adresse mail : {{ $email }}

Téléphone : {{ $telephone }}

Téléphone facultatif {{ $telephone2 }}

Horaires pouvant être joignable : {{ $horaires }}
```

Comment: can you post your emails.hello view structure ? So I can have look into that how you are trying to access the variable ?

Comment: Edited previous post

Comment: for which variable its saying undefined ? can you tell us the error ?

Comment: see my below answer, it seems that you are missing the `informations` variable to pass with `email array`

Comment: Saw the answer, but still getting this common error : ErrorException in helpers.php line 469 about htmlentities

Answer (score 0):

in your `email.hello` view, you are calling `$informations` variable

```
Informations : {{ $informations }}
```

but you are not passing `$informations` variable from `email` method

**this one is missing**

```
  array(
        'informations' => $request->get('informations'),
    ),
```

**Updated**

instead of using

```
$request->get()
```

use this

```
$request->input()
```

---

**my email script**

```
$to_username    =   $to_array['to_username'];
$from_goodname  =   $to_array['from_goodname'];
$link           =   $to_array['link'];
$link           =   '<a href="'.$link.'" target="_blank"> '.$link.'</a>';

$user_data      =   ['to_username'=>$to_username, 'from_goodname'=>$from_goodname, 'link'=>$link];

return Mail::send('emails.invite', $user_data, function($message) use ($to_array) {

    $to_username    =   $to_array['to_username'];
    $to_goodname    =   $to_array['to_username'];

    $to_subject =   'New Invitation to SMP System!';

    $message->to($to_username, $to_username)->subject($to_subject);
});
```

**My view content**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Invitation</h2>

                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <p>Hello {{$to_username}}</p>
                    <p> You have been invited by {!!$from_goodname!!} to Secure Messaging Portal, 
                        Please follow the link to complete the information steps.
                        <br /><br />
                    </p>
                    <p> {!!$link!!} </p>
                    <p>Thanks</p>
                </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "ErrorException in helpers.php line 469:
htmlentities expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in view blade

Comment: are you using any `helpers.php` file or you created any ? also see my updated answer

Comment: Deleted the "get" for "input" still the same prob. I don't think so but how can I confirm that?

Comment: do one thing, remove all variable from your email `view` just type simple text eg: `hello world` and in mail method `\Mail::send('emails.hello',[]....`  pass empty array, then check the result ?

Comment: Mail sent, I get back into contact form and the email content has "Hello world".

Comment: good, its mean that there is something with your email array data using in view, now just use single variable in your email view. eg: in your email method just pass `['event_type'=>$request->input('event_type')]` and in email view, just do this

`Type d'évènement: {{ $event_type }}`

Comment: Undefined variable in email view, maybe because you using [] ?
edit: removed them, i get email with type d'evenement, but not the information in variable.

Comment: That code is not working when I add [ ] to the code.
Errorexception in line 2: undefined variable: event_type

Comment: which php version you are using ?

Comment: \Mail::send('emails.hello',
        array(
       ['event_type'=>$request->input('event_type')],
        ),

Comment: try this
`\Mail::send('emails.hello', array( 'event_type'=>'this is random string for testing')........,),`

Comment: I get the mail with the string in like "Type d'évènement : This is random string for testing".

Comment: ok its mean that, there may issue with your $request, do one thing, once you submit the form then in your `store()` method write this, and tell me the results.. `echo "<pre>"; print_r($request->all()); die();` also share your `ContactFormRequest` code

Comment: check previous comments for ContactFormRequest 
+ Controller

Comment: what results you got after dumping your request, `echo "<pre>"; print_r($request->all()); die();`

Comment: I get unexpected ")" line 23

Comment: found the prob, now i get this mozilla
Array
(
    [_token] => 2VBuQuVZBaQ8LiAe5wh5eriYuf0PLItt1YVNjuqG
    [event_types] => cocktail
    [date] => ryhegagtae
    [personnes] => 5_20
    [lieu] => egaegae
    [rayon_km] => 20
    [accessoires] => Array
        (
            [0] => bloc_sanitaire
            [1] => chapiteau
        )

    [informations] => aegaegae
    [civilite] => association
    [prenom] => aegae
    [nom] => gae
    [telephone] => 
    [email] => eagaega@gmail.com
    [telephone2] => 
    [horaires] => 
)

Comment: ok, now pass all your input into `Mail` method. eg: `Mail::send('emails.invite', $request->all(),......` and use form variable into your email view. eg `Type {{$event_types}}`

Comment: \Mail::send('emails.hello', $request->all(),
        'event_type' => $request->input('event__type'),


    );
like this ? Because i get this error FatalErrorException in AboutController.php line 16: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW

Comment: use it like this `\Mail::send('emails.hello',$request->all(), function($message){ .......`

Comment: when submit, TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:

Comment: If i chage the string entries, i do not get Token error.

Comment: after this line `{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'contact', 'class' => 'form')) !!}` type this `{!!Form::token();!!}`

Comment: Haha we getting closer, i get this error and email view updated in the comment above
ErrorException in helpers.php line 469: htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: C:\wamp\www\Comptoirduparasol\Comptoir\resources\views\emails\hello.blade.php)

Comment: can you give your system access, are any code area where you deployed it. So I can have a look, exactly after 2 hours ?, it will be easy for me to debug the issue

Comment: No where but I also forgot to say, i have php tabs in header, and i call them using variables in select.
<?php
$event_types = [
...
];

Comment: how amazing it is.... of course it will give you error, you accessing the same variable, just change the variable naming and access in `Mail` method

Comment: I'm sorry.. Now the submit doesn't work and I don't get any errors.. Maybe I can reach you somewhere so I can show you my project? Haven't enough reputatation for chat

Comment: revert your code to last working state, and just try this thing. in your Email view, donot use this input field value `$event_types` and use others, check what results you get... means remove this line `Type d'évènement :  {{ $event_types }} </br>`

Comment: I did a clean up on form, controller and now everything is working fine except event type and checkboxs

Comment: Event type is working now, I'm just missing checkbox part. Thats why I get htmlentities error

Comment: Let me know if u have a solution for checkbox part, you been very helpful, thanks alot !!

Comment: How I can know about checkbox, until and unless you didn't tell me about that

Comment: above I use the variable $accessoires associated to checkboxs in the form. I'm getting htmlentities error

Comment: for `$accessoires` try this and tell me the results. `{{`print_r($accessoires, true);}}`

Comment: I get error using it with ";".
Without it works but appears in the mail view like this Les accessoires nécessaires : Array ( [0] => element [1] => element [2] => element [3] => element ).

Comment: its seems that you have created this `$accessoires` as array somewhere in your header or any other file, try to use those labeling which are not already defined and initialized. means unique variable/form names

Comment: You are amazing, thanks for everything :)
I know I'm being annoying but if you have any idea on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280428/deploy-laravel-5-ovh